# How to Serve Static Content (.html, .js, etc) with Express.JS

Tags: express

Express isn't letting my web application load up AngularJS.  My web application has a directory structure that basically looks like this:

```
\root
    server.js
    \angularApplication
        index.html
        \assets
            angular.js
```

My server.js looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/angularApplication/index.html');
});

app.use("/angularScripts", express.static(__dirname + '/angularApplication/assets'));
```

`index.html` loads fine, but the script doesn't load.  I get this 404 error:

> GET http://localhost:8000/angularScripts/angular.js

If I reference AngularJS in my HTML normally:

```
<script src="/relative-path-to/angular.js"></script>
```

then Express still won't get the files.  What am I doing incorrectly, and why does Express refuse to serve up any my scripts?

Comment: http://localhost:8000/ works?

Comment: @JuniorCompressor Yeah, index.html is loading fine on port 8000.  It's just that none of my scripts or stylesheets load - only everything I've got referenced via CDN.  I'm having a very hard time understanding how normal static content is served by ExpressJS. How do I reference these arcane `app.use` blocks in the HTML on the front-end?

Comment: It should work. I would check for permissions and typos in the folder name or js filename

Comment: @JuniorCompressor I went ahead and updated my question - I finally found a way to hack this together.  I'd post this as an answer, but I'm a little bit unsure if this is the correct usage.

Comment: What's smelly about it, this is similar to example from [ExpressJS documentation](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.built-in)

Comment: @aarosil It seemed weird to me because every time I reference a script, it looks redundant: (`angularJS/angular.js`, `bootstrap/boostrap.css', 'LESS/less.css`).  I also don't see a way to just serve up every file in a directory.

Comment: @aarosil on top of that, the example from the docs does not show how the resultant paths are referenced on the client-side, which has been frustrating for me

Comment: Alex express.static does serve up every file in the directory that's the point :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
app.use("/angularJS", express.static(__dirname + '/angularApplication/assets'));
```

But only if I reference the script in the HTML like this:

```
<script src="angularJS/angular.js"></script>
```

Obviously this isn't how `app.use` is meant to be used.  The better solution I've found is this:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/angularApplication/assets'));
// app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/angularApplication/etc'));
```

These will serve up all of the files in the directory, and thus the scripts and stylesheets can be referenced like this instead on the front-end:

```
<script src="angular.js"></script>
```